# How to Unpack/ Simplify Anonymous Inner Class

Tags: java, anonymous-class, simplify, anonymous-inner-class, cqengine

The goal of this post is to find out how to avoid using anonymous inner classes.

I have not worked extensively with `inner anonymous classes` but I am trying to simplify the following lines of code in someone's package `examples.introduction.novice.simpler.model;`

```
public class Person {
    public final String name;

// --- Attribute
    public static final Attribute<Person, String> NAME = new SimpleAttribute<Person, String>("name") {
        public String getValue(Person person, QueryOptions queryOptions) { return person.name; }
    };

}
```

So to unpack the above & make it easier to read I rewrote it so (please correct me if I am wrong):

```
public class Person {
    public final String name;
    
    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    
    // TODO: Simplify
    // ----------- Attributes -------------
    public static final Attribute<Person, String> NAME = new Name<Person, String>("name") ;

}
```

And ofcourse I created the `Name` class so :

```
public class Name<O, A> extends SimpleAttribute<O, A> {
    public Name(String attributeName) {
        super(attributeName);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String getValue(Person person, QueryOptions queryOptions) { return person.name; }

    @Override
    public A getValue(O arg0, QueryOptions arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


}
```

However, I am getting an error so :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at examples.introduction.novice.simpler.model.Introduction.main(Introduction.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attribute 'name' (class examples.introduction.novice.simpler.model.Name) is invalid, cannot read generic type information from it. Attributes should typically EITHER be declared in code with generic type information as a (possibly anonymous) subclass of one of the provided attribute types, OR you can use a constructor of the attribute which allows the types to be specified manually.
    at com.googlecode.cqengine.attribute.support.AbstractAttribute.readGenericObjectType(AbstractAttribute.java:139)
    at com.googlecode.cqengine.attribute.support.AbstractAttribute.<init>(AbstractAttribute.java:43)
    at com.googlecode.cqengine.attribute.SimpleAttribute.<init>(SimpleAttribute.java:55)
    at examples.introduction.novice.simpler.model.Name.<init>(Name.java:11)
    at examples.introduction.novice.simpler.model.Person.<clinit>(Person.java:23)
    ... 1 more
```

To recap:
I am trying to simplify the following example in the following package (this is the original working example that I am trying to simplify and it has two classes: the main class called `Introduction.java` and the accompanying class called `Person.java`):
https://github.com/mrarthurwhite/CQEngineIntroExample/tree/master/src/examples/introduction/novice

The attempt at simplifying this is in the following package (it just attempts to unpack the `Person.java` class :
https://github.com/mrarthurwhite/CQEngineIntroExample/tree/master/src/examples/introduction/novice/simpler/model

As the kind & patient reader may observe from above , I am trying to unpack the anonymous inner class for `Attribute`  . This is the link to the `Attribute` class & the `cqengine` library:
https://github.com/npgall/cqengine/blob/master/code/src/main/java/com/googlecode/cqengine/attribute/Attribute.java

Also following is the link to the child class `SimpleAttribute` which is a descendant of `Attribute`:
https://github.com/npgall/cqengine/blob/master/code/src/main/java/com/googlecode/cqengine/attribute/SimpleAttribute.java

Comment: If it worked before and was already easily readable, why the need to change it (and possibly break it in the process)?

Comment: @QBrute I am trying to unpack the anonymous inner class because some programmers are not very familiar with it,  including myself. As you can see , I don't understand anonymous inner classes that well, when I tried to unpack it I get the aforementioned error.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Name extends SimpleAttribute<Person, String> {
    public Name() {
        super("name");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue(Person person, QueryOptions queryOptions) { 
        return person.name; 
    }
}
```

Try this.
If you make a new generic implementation you have to basically use reflection to get the value.  If you do that it will be way more complicated and not simplier.

Comment: thanks! this is what I was looking for. A way of avoiding writing anonymous inner classes. When I used your definition of the Name class, I see that `Person.java` gives a compile error `The type Name is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Person, String>`
Would you kindly upvote this question, someone is maliciously downvoting it & that may cause other responders to not notice it.

Comment: you need to make the name object like new Name()

Comment: @Arthur W the other answer is wrong because there should be no parameter in the construction. the named parameter will never be another attribute other than "name". mark mine as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

For your code, the Java compiler would generate a more specific, non-generic concrete class, like this (of course the name would be different):

```
public class Name extends SimpleAttribute<Person, String> {
    public Name(String attributeName) {
        super(attributeName);
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue(Person person, QueryOptions queryOptions) { return person.name; }

}
```

Notice how the superclass type is `SimpleAttribute<Person, String>`. The type arguments for `SimpleAttribute` are all concrete types, rather than type variables `O` and `A` like in your attempt.

And you'd use it like this:

```
public static final Attribute<Person, String> NAME = new Name("name");
```

Judging from the exception message,

> Attribute 'name' (class examples.introduction.novice.simpler.model.Name) is invalid, cannot read generic type information from it.

the library that you are using relies on this behaviour (the fact that the type arguments are concrete types) to read the type arguments. It probably calls something to the effect of:

```
((ParameterizedType)NAME.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()
```

If the type arguments for `SimpleAttribute` are `O` and `A`, like in your attempt at unpacking the anonymous class, the returned array will not have any real types, and that's possibly why it says "cannot read generic type information".

On the other hand, if you use an anonymous class (or the code from the beginning of the answer), then the generated inner class will have `SimpleAttribute<Person, String>` as the superclass, and the library would be able to read useful information from it.

Also note that, even if the library doesn't happen to read the generic type arguments, your unpacking of the anonymous class still doesn't do the same thing as the original code. Namely, the way you overrode the abstract method:

```
@Override
public A getValue(O arg0, QueryOptions arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

is not the same as how the abstract method was overridden in the original code:

```
public String getValue(Person person, QueryOptions queryOptions) { return person.name; }
```

The other overload of `getValue` that you defined in `Name` isn't really relevant.

Comment: the overriden `getvalue` method was generated by eclipse because without it, the class gives a compiler error : `The type Name<O,A> must implement the inherited abstract method SimpleAttribute<O,A>.getValue(O, QueryOptions)`  I am trying to avoid using inner anonymous classes - is there a way of doing that?

Comment: @ArthurW Exactly, at that point you should realise there is something wrong with your "unpacking". The overload that contributes to implementing the abstract class is the one that returns null. The other one is not relevant. See your mistake? If `Name` is generic, it must have a `getValue` method that takes an `O` and a `QueryOptions`, but that will never work since you want to return a _person's_ name, so `Name` should not be generic. See the beginning of the answer for a correct translation of the anonymous class to a named class. What is not clear?

Comment: What is not clear is how I can avoid using anonymous inner classes altogether? What implementation would avoid this altogether? Apologies but for some reason my cognitive abilities are not optimal at this hour (for some strange reason). @Sweeper

Comment: @ArthurW Have you seen the [latest edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68771873/revisions) of my answer? I added an example of how you would rewrite the declaration of `NAME` to use the _named_ class `Name`.

Comment: Your recommendations worked! thanks! amazing! I am not sure how or why, I will go over your answer after my thinking is less foggy...